# Three-column design: one static header, one side-bar with v-scroll, one center-box with v/h-scroll

Tags: xaml, silverlight-3.0

How would you code this design:

http://roosteronacid.com/xaml.png

**Update:**

Here's where I'm at:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- v-scroll on contents -->
    <StackPanel x:Name="sidebar" Grid.Column="0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="top-box" Margin="4, 4, 4, 4"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFCECECE" />

        <StackPanel x:Name="bottom-box" Grid.Column="0">
            <StackPanel Margin="4, 4, 4, 4" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <controls:GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" Width="2" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Black" />

    <!-- no scroll -->
    <StackPanel x:Name="static-top-box" Grid.Column="1" Height="60"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="AliceBlue">
        <StackPanel Margin="4, 4, 4, 4" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- v/h-scroll on contents -->
    <StackPanel x:Name="v-h-scroll-box" Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto"
                Margin="0,60,0,0" Background="Beige">
        <StackPanel Margin="4, 4, 4, 4" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Grid` with two rows and two columns. One control in cell 0,0 with a `RowSpan` of 2. Each of the other controls in cells 1,0 and 1,1 respectively. Row 1 is sized absolute and Row 2 is percentage sized. How you govern the display of scrollbars is up to your design and what controls you host in the grid.

#### Update

I believe you just need to host your `StackPanel` instances inside `ScrollViewer` instances. This should give you the scrollbars that you need.

Comment: So the Grid element is the only element able to show scroll-bars?

Comment: No, lots of controls can show scrollbars - the grid element is just to provide the layout you want. Whether you have scrollbars or not is down to what controls you put in those cells.

Comment: @Jeff: Updated my question with some code. Perhaps you can help me implement scroll-capability?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this so there might be a typo or two but it should point you in the right direction. The ScrollViewers will place the scroll bars and will figure out whether to display vertical and horizontal scroll bars based on the size of their content. There are also properties that allow you to specify whether you want are scroll bar in each direction but I've found that the automatic detection usually works best.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        Left Pane Content
    </ScrollViewer>

    <TopPaneContent DockPanel.Dock="Top" />

    <ScrollViewer>
        Main Body Content
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

I just noticed the Silverlight tag. To use a DockPanel in Silverlight you'll need to use the Silverlight Toolkit. Instructions on how to add it are [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/SilverlightDockPanel12042008100129AM/SilverlightDockPanel.aspx) and you can find it [here](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight).